# lamson: mail address format

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, lamson

I'm using Lamson SMTP server with a Queue receiver for a project. It works fine, but from time to time, I get weird address emails in the "to" and "cc" headers from the email sent with mutt, with the default testing environment.

ex. an email sent to

```
test@test.com
```

with mutt will be sent to the SMTPReceiver, placed in maildir and processed with the QueueReceiver. What I finally get is something like

```
test@xn--est-o0a.com
```

I'm guessing it has to do with encoding but since Lamson is supposed to provide clean unicode strings...i don't know.

Any thought?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this tool](http://mct.verisign-grs.com/conversiontool/convertServlet?input=xn--est-o0a&type=PUNYCODE), xn--est-o0a means ŧest, not test.

Comment: Thanks! The input contained errors. Your tool helped to spot them.