# Lamson for multiple Django projects

Tags: django, lamson

I'd like to know how to use Django and Lamson together in such a way that Lamson can utilize several Django projects.

I have several Django websites running on my server (e.g., domain1.com, domain2.com and domain3.com). I'm using virtual hosts for each website. Each Django project uses its own virtual environment, thus enabling them to use different versions of Django (and possibly even Python).

I'd like to use Lamson to do simple email handling: forward the email to correct recipients. For instance, list1@domain1.com have some subscribers and the Django project corresponding to domain1.com has that information. Or firstname.lastname@domain2.com could be an alias for a real address which is known by the Django project domain2.com. Typically, the information is not in the database as such directly, but one needs to perform some kind of project specific logic. For instance, men@domain1.com would filter only male user accounts and then return their email addresses as a list.

There are some instructions on how to combine Django and Lamson so that Lamson can access the database of a Django project easily. However, I have only found solutions for the case when there is only one Django project AND Lamson&Django use the same/similar (virtual) environment. That kind of solution is described, for instance, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106326/hooking-up-lamson-with-django-1-4), but I don't think it can be applied here.

So, how can Lamson communicate with several Django projects in order to translate an email address to a list of real email addresses?